# Access parent file metadata from embedded extractor processing

Tags: java, apache-tika

I'm working with Tika and using the Java library for it. Using a custom implementation of a `EmbeddedDocumentExtractor` with a `RecursiveParserWrapper` to process embedded files. This custom `EmbeddedDocumentExtractor` uses the override of the `parseEmbedded` method to process the files within a given container file.

I'm trying to identify if there is anyway to access the parent containers metadata while the embedded file is being processed. Or, does Tika not finish with the parent metadata until all embedded files are processed?

I've tried setting the `RecursiveParserWrapperHandler` on the context object and along the `ParseContext` to the `EmbeddedDocumentExtractor` like this:

```java
TikaConfig config = new TikaConfig(TikaProcessor.class.getResourceAsStream("/tika-config.xml"));
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser(config);
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
ContentHandlerFactory factory = new BasicContentHandlerFactory(BasicContentHandlerFactory.HANDLER_TYPE.BODY, 100000);

RecursiveWrapperParser wrapper = new RecursiveParserWrapper(parser);
RecursiveParserWrapperHandler handler = new RecursiveParserWrapperHandler(factory);
MyCustomEmbeddedDocumentExtractor myCustomExtractor = new MyCustomEmbeddedDocumentExtractor(context);

context.set(RecursiveParserWrapper.class, wrapper);
context.set(RecursiveParserWrapperHandler.class, handler);
context.set(EmbeddedDocumentExtractor.class, myCustomExtractor);
context.set(Parser.class, parser);

Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
wrapper.parse(someInputStream, handler, metadata, context);
```

and then attempting to access it inside of the custom extractor:

```java
public class MyCustomEmbeddedDocumentExtractor extends ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor {
    ParseContext context;
    
    public MyCustomEmbeddedDocumentExtractor(ParseContext parentContext) {
        super(parentContext);
        this.context = parentContext;
    }

    public boolean shouldParseEmbedded(Metadata metadata) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void parseEmbedded(InputStream inputStream, ContentHandler contentHandler, Metadata metadata, boolean outputHtml) throws SAXException, IOException {
        // do some stuff
        RecursiveParserWrapperHandler wrapperHandler = (RecursiveParserWrapperHandler) context.get(RecursiveParserWrapperHandler.class);
        if (wrapperHandler != null) {
           List<Metadata> parentMetadata = wrapperHandler.getMetadataList();
           // ==> List has size of zero here? <==
        }
    }
}
```

The `getMetadataList()` call doesn't seem to contain the parent metadata in the embedded extractor. For what it's worth, on subsequent `parseEmbedded` calls, the call to `getMetadataList()` does start populating with children metadata, so I know this is somewhat working.

Comment: Based on what I'm seeing in the Tika source for the `RecursiveParserWrapperHandler`, the parent metadata isn't available in the list until all embedded documents have been processed: https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/41a99cce34f90259ad8775cb8abbdbcc19e7ca27/tika-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/sax/RecursiveParserWrapperHandler.java#L128

Hoping maybe someone else knows of a way to retrieve this through some other internal Tika source?

Comment: It will vary somewhat between file formats, but for at least some, the embedded document will be triggered as soon as it is found, which may be before any of the metadata has been found + processed

Comment: You're both right.  The parent metadata object isn't added to the list until the end of the document (https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/sax/RecursiveParserWrapperHandler.java#L127).   Why do you need the parent metadata?  Is there another way to accomplish what you need, short of implementing your own RecursiveParserWrapperHandler?

Comment: @TimAllison The main thing I was looking to achieve was to be able to apply metadata from a "parent" container file to a given "child" embedded file if the child file didn't have that information. For example, if a file doesn't have created/modified dates, derive from the parents. It seems to accomplish this you would have to run the "parent" file through a parser by itself to extract this information, and then send the file through another parser using `RecursiveParserWrapperHandler` while supplying the parents metadata from the first run.

Comment: We have a MetadataFilter that is applied post parse per metadata object that allows you to modify metadata before the data is returned.  I think there's also a need for a post-parse filter that takes the list of metadata objects from a parse and modifies it...perhaps enriches the container document or pushes data from the parent into the contained files.  If you open an issue on our JIRA (https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TIKA), I'll see what we can do.